# Problem booting into Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, 18.04

I have UBUNTU 16LTS installed in one disk and 17 on another and it was functioning perfectly. Recently I clean installed 18.04LTS on the disk with version 17 using a USB flash drive. Installation finished without any issues and the new OS showed up nicely on the Grub screen. However, whenever I select 18.04LTS to boot into, the screen goes blank after the purple ubuntu screen and never reaches the login prompt. I have tried boot repair from startup disk, which did not help. What might be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly describe the method by which you "upgraded the 17 version to 18.04LTS"

Comment: Done... hope this helps

Comment: Do you get to see the Ubuntu logo with the incrementing dots underneath? Is this an older computer? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema Yes... that screen stays for a few seconds, followed by a blank screen. This is a new computer I assembled last year. Before 18.04, it was a charm!

Comment: Search here on AU for "black screen" and you'll find your answer.